# Is there a limit to outputting entries in 'free' version of Craft CMS?

Tags: templating, entries

I am outputting all my entries and it seems that on the front end, it isn't displaying entries from N to Z. I see those entries in the backend. The entries on the front end:

http://www.colorcomputergames.com/games

The template conditional doesn't have any limits on N to Z or the number of entries to show. The entries are enabled.

Is this due to using the free version of Craft CMS or some other setting?

My template code is:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set title = "Games" %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').order('title') %}
{% block content %}
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a> ... {% set publishers = entry.GamesPublisher %}{% for publisher in publishers %}<a href="{{ publisher.url }}">{{ publisher.title }}</a> {% endfor %}{% if entry.GamesGenre is not empty %}{% for category in entry.GamesGenre %}{{ category.title }}{% endfor %}{% endif %}{% if entry.GamesReleaseYear is not empty %} {{ entry.GamesReleaseYear.format('Y') }}{% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft will limit the number of elements returned by default to 100, so if you're expecting to get > 100 entries, that's probably what you're running into.

To grab all entries, use:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').order('title').limit(null) %}
```

Note that this default limit of 100 no longer exists in Craft 3.